# How to pipe to local terminal/processes from node webkit desktop app?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, terminal, node-webkit

I'm writing a node webkit desktop app for Ubuntu. 
I want to open up a terminal and type some things in the terminal from a click from the desktop app. 
What modules can I use to hook up my desktop app to the terminal?

Comment: Just want to mention that on OS X we do that with AppleScript. Not sure about Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the terminal window to be open and visible? Probably not, so you should be able to use Node's [`child_process`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) module to execute a command in the background. Just do this on startup.